# Loop fadeIn / fadeOut controlling opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, opacity, fadeout

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/BGW2y/

I want to control the opacity. I simple do not want the links to go completely fadeout. I need them to remain visible and only fade out to about 0.3 opacity? How can I change the code to enable this?

```
fadeloop('.soundDiv-link, .soundDiv-link2',1000,4200,true);
fadeloop('.videoDiv-link, .videoDiv-link2',4300,1300,true);
fadeloop('.imagesDiv-link, .imagesDiv-link2',1500,4100,true);
fadeloop('.aboutDiv-link',4000,1000,true);

function fadeloop(el,timeout,timein,loop){
var $el = $(el),intId,fn = function(){
     $el.fadeOut(timeout).fadeIn(timein);
};
fn();
if(loop){
    intId = setInterval(fn,timeout+timein+100);
    return intId;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.fadeTo()` http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
$el.fadeTo(timeout, .3).fadeTo(timein, 1);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/BGW2y/1/)